# Remove subset rows of other rows in SQL

Tags: sql, concatenation, subset, bitwise-operators, exists

I've this table below that includes `ID`, and five indicator columns: `x1`, ..., `x5`:

[image]

I need to remove duplicates based on this logic:

For each `ID`, we look at the values of `x1`, ..., `x5`, and we remove the ones that are subset of other row. For example, for ID=1, row #3 is a subset of row #2, so we remove row #3. Also, row #4 is NOT a subset of row #2, so we keep it.

Here is the expected final view of the table:

[image]

Comment: 1) What RDBMS are using 2)How do you determine the ordering of the rows in this data, as order seems to be pretty important 3) How big is this data... I fear the number of comparisons that need to be made may be huge. 4) Is "ID" superfluous here? Are you saying you look for a "Subset" even across different ID numbers?

Comment: Are there duplicate rows in the table?

Comment: MySQL. For ordering, let's say we use row numbers. We need to do this per ID, not across all IDs.

Comment: @forpas.. I am referring to duplicates here where row are subset of other rows.

Comment: I mean if all ID, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 are the same in 2 different rows.

Comment: I edited the title.

Comment: I've already done that so there should not be any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First concatenate all values of the 5 columns so that you get a binary string like '100101' which can be converted to a base 10 number, say aliased `value`, with the function [`CONV()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv).

Assuming there are no duplicate rows in the table as you mention in your comment, a row *#X* should be considered a subset of another row *#Y* if the result of the [bitwise `OR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-or) between the `value`s of the 2 rows returns the `value` of *#Y*:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM tablename t2
  WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID 
    AND (t1.x1, t1.x2, t1.x3, t1.x4, t1.x5) <>
        (t2.x1, t2.x2, t2.x3, t2.x4, t2.x5)
    AND CONV(CONCAT(t1.x1, t1.x2, t1.x3, t1.x4, t1.x5), 2, 10) |
        CONV(CONCAT(t2.x1, t2.x2, t2.x3, t2.x4, t2.x5), 2, 10) =
        CONV(CONCAT(t2.x1, t2.x2, t2.x3, t2.x4, t2.x5), 2, 10)
);
```

Or, for MySql 8.0+:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, CONV(CONCAT(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5), 2, 10) value
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT t1.ID, t1.x1, t1.x2, t1.x3, t1.x4, t1.x5
FROM cte t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM cte t2
  WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID 
    AND t2.value <> t1.value
    AND t1.value | t2.value = t2.value
);
```

If you want to delete the subset rows, use a self join of the table like this:

```
DELETE t1
FROM tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
ON t2.ID = t1.ID
AND (t1.x1, t1.x2, t1.x3, t1.x4, t1.x5) <>
    (t2.x1, t2.x2, t2.x3, t2.x4, t2.x5)
AND CONV(CONCAT(t1.x1, t1.x2, t1.x3, t1.x4, t1.x5), 2, 10) |
    CONV(CONCAT(t2.x1, t2.x2, t2.x3, t2.x4, t2.x5), 2, 10) =
    CONV(CONCAT(t2.x1, t2.x2, t2.x3, t2.x4, t2.x5), 2, 10);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=53e8f9c345a58e4f103746ed13d18054).